# Sub-collections in REST api

Tags: rest, api, collections, resources

How many sub-collections can have a resource?

Just imagine that we have this model:
accounts -> posts -> comments

Everything is clear for accounts-posts pair. 
/accounts/{account_id}/posts/{post_id}

But what about comments? What is a proper way to point to a single comment?

/posts/{post_id}/comments/{comment_id}

or

/accounts/{account_id}/posts/{post_id}/comments/{comment_id}

or (direct pointing)

comments/{comment_id}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general rule of thumb is to only go one layer of subresources deep. An account may have many posts like you show, and a post may have many comments, but since the post id is unique, including the account id is a bit redundant when trying to get the comments for a post.

/accounts/:account_id/posts

/posts/:post_id/comments

Ruby On Rails also lists this in their docs (just for a bit of a citation). https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#limits-to-nesting

Additionally, if you already have the id of a resource you don’t need to nest it. As short of a route that gets the job done is preferred.

/comments/:id